# Why does my React app start on my Backend port?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a React and NodeJS app. Here is my server/index.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const items_controller = require('./controllers/items_controller');

app.get('/items', items_controller.getAllItems);

const port = process.env.BACKEND_PORT; // 3333
const server = app.listen( port, () => console.log(`Listening on port: ${port}`) );
```

When I'm doing npm start it's trying to start React server on my backend server which is 3333 when by default it's 3000. Does anybody know a reason?

Comment: Where it says that the default is `3000`?

Comment: Where is it configured to use port `3333`?

Comment: @AkosK it's not saying anywhere but the command react-scripts start starts web dev server on port 3000 as far as I know

Comment: @GanapatiVS only my backend is configured to use port 3333, that's the thing

Comment: Please post your `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible reasons for this issue:

- You might be having something running on `PORT` `3000`([check if any process is using it](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-check-if-port-is-in-use-command/))

If this is the case, `react-scripts` will [find next available free port](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/scripts/start.js#L85) (which is probably `3333?`) and start the server there.

- You might have exported `PORT` environment variable.

If `PORT` environment variable is available `react-scripts` [uses it to start the server](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1083).

Comment: That actually worked for me. I had PORT variable redefined in my .env file. Thank you!